# MVC Password Format : Hash , Validate the user without keying Username/Password

Tags: c#, facebook, model-view-controller, hash, membership

I'm developing an MVC C# module which has User Creation password format set to Hash. Now, I also have a Facebook login module besides the normal login . This Facebook login will merge with the normal login if the username the same.

My problem here is, when I merged the Facebook login, both this account will share the same password. I can get the user which return the username and password, and use Membership.ValidateUser to validate . But because of the password is hashed, I can't validate it for the Facebook login. Do I need to decrypt it first, or any other ideas?

Comment: You cannot "decrypt" a hashed password.

Comment: You would encrypt password rather than hash it so you can decrypt back.

Comment: Are you actually storing facebook login details? I thought you were only given login tokens to use?

Comment: No I didn't store facebook login details . If the Facebook login is merged with the normal user , it will be sharing the same login information as the normal user .

Comment: How about this ? How to validate the password without hashing it instead with Membership.ValidateUser() , since when I obtained it , it is already in hashed format .

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to worry about the password at all. You can just get the user that is associated with the facebook account and then authenticate that user manually

```
var userName= YourRepository.GetUsernameByFacebookId(returnedFacebookId);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName);
```